# docker-compose.yml - Additional property Version is not allowed

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, dockerfile

whenever I want to run this docker-compose.yml file I get:
**(root) Additional property Version is not allowed**

But when I take out the first line with the version (Version: "3.7"
) in the file it suddenly works .

Can someone explain me why?

```
---
Version: "3.7"

services:
  notebook:
    image: jupyter/datascience-notebook:latest
    environment:
      - JUPYTER_TOKEN=hi
    volumes:
      - /home/kali
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    container_name: jupyter-notebook
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like `version` with a small `v`. There is no supported docker-compose property like `Version`